# Apply script to multiple Video Tags with unique id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that applies a skin to a Video tag with id="videoLabel1"

```
$(function() {
    $('#videoLabel1').vp1_html5_Video({
        skin: 'futuristicChrome',
        seekBarAdjust:255
    });
});
```

I would like to modify the script to apply the skin to any number of Video tags each labelled id="videoLabelX" where X is any number I choose, to keep each id unique.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for selecting the video tags with `id="videoLabelX"`? If not, a cleaner alternative may be to add a class to all the video tags, i.e. `class="video-tags"`, and then select that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use the starts-with selector http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$(function() {
    $('[id^="videoLabel"]').vp1_html5_Video({
        skin: 'futuristicChrome',
        seekBarAdjust:255
    });
});
```

or add a class (`class="videoLabel"`) to the video tags and use that as the selector

```
$(function() {
    $('.videoLabel').vp1_html5_Video({
        skin: 'futuristicChrome',
        seekBarAdjust:255
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use an `attribute-starts-with` selector (`^=`):

```
$('[id^=videoLabel]').vp1_html5_Video({
    skin: 'futuristicChrome',
    seekBarAdjust:255
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

***However***, you are better off adding a class to your video tag if you have control of the HTML:

```
<video class="skinnedVideoClass" id="videoLabel4">...</video>
```

JS:

```
$('.skinnedVideoClass').vp1_html5_Video({ ... });
```

Comment: For some reason the class option doesn't work. I did try it. I suspect the main Javascript (which I'm not confident enough to try and change) expects the Video tag to have an id. However, attribute-starts-with selector seems to work perfectly, so many thanks to both of you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: You can have *both* an ID and a class.  That should make your main JavaScript happy, as well as this piece.

Comment: @JeffB - `$('[id^=videoLabel]')` should be `$('[id^="videoLabel"]')`, quotes around what to search for.

Comment: @SolomonClosson: According to the docs, as well as my experience, the quotes are optional.  They are only necessary if your search string is not a single word.  From the doc: `value: An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string.`

Comment: @SolomonClosson: Yet the spec contradicts you.  Works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/HcW8U/

Comment: Lol. You had me questioning myself for a minute there.  I thought I had used code just like this on a number of occasions before.

Comment: Javascript is not my field at all but, for your interest It's working for me with the quotes. If you want to see my practice page it is here http://new.chemistry-teaching-resources.com/Video_Skin/futuristicChrome.html

Comment: You could also just select by tag, btw, if you want all the videos to have the skin:  `$('video').vp1_html5_Video({...});`